# MySQL INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

В БД 4 поля

```
id(int), 
id_session(varchar), 
id_goods(int), 
quantity(int)

INSERT INTO basket 
  (id_session, id_goods) 
VALUES 
  ('{$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']}', '{$_POST['id']}') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 1"
```

При повторной записи хочу увеличивать значение на единицу, но в итоге получаю задвоение записи. Где я неправ?

Comment: Если запись задваивается, значит таблица такое позволяет. А раз она позволяет, значит на таблице нет уникального ключа по нужным вам колонкам. on duplicate работает только в ситуации, когда правильные уникальные ключи есть.

Comment: как в одном запросе тогда логику построить, проверку записи по 2 столбцам, если так нет, то добавить, если есть, увеличить значение

Comment: Если по 2 столбцам, то создайте уникальный индекс по этим 2м столбцам, что бы физически нельзя было вставить 2 одинаковые строки (`create unique index basket_uniq on basket(id_session, id_goods)`) и ваш запрос отлично справится. Вы же видите, что в самом запросе нигде не указано по каким правилам проверять существование записи, это от того что такое правило должно быть создано на таблице

Comment: Спасибо большое. Проблема решена.

Answer (score -1):

Во первых не стоит вставлять значения из куки и $_POST напрямую в базу, а ошибка вот

```
INSERT INTO basket (id_session, id_goods) VALUES ('{$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']}', '{$_POST['id']}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE basket SET quantity = quantity + 1
```