# Как ограничить число загружаемых аватарок на сервер пользователем?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как ограничить число загружаемых аватарок на сервер пользователем?
Допустим одну загрузил, если ещё пытаешься, то картинка перезапишется, а не снова загрузится.
б.д.
[image: б.д.]

Получается у меня как: пользователь загружает картинку. Картинка попадает в папку на сервере images. Из базы достаю название и вставляю его в тег img в атрибут src

Comment: Записывайте кол-во аватарок в базу, добавьте поле со счетчиком, если больше 5, перезаписывайте ту которая была добавлена раньше всего
Или без счетчика, если в базе записи храните

Comment: При добавлении, выбираете все аватарки (count()), если меньше пяти, записываем, если больше - перезаписываем

Comment: если на картинке изображена таблица с загруженными файлами, то никак

Comment: Загрузка аватарок производится только авторизованным пользователем, поэтому мы знаем имя текущего залогиненного пользователя. Можно даже не  считать для него count записей у которых поле name равно имени текущего залогиненного, а использовать insert-or-update (которая в общем-то ничего кроме modified и avatar не обновит. А вот файл нужно обрабатывать отдельно, там только считать, был ли аватар ранее.

Comment: @AK это функция insert-or-update в codeigniter используется? или это общая какая то функция, я просто такой не вижу

Comment: Это конструкция mysql `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` тут например смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/974440/213987 или в документации mysql